# VSCode: Как в своем расширении установить обработчик события на смену языка в редакторе?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Делаю расширение для VS Code. Задача: в статус-бар добавлять элемент при работе с определенным языком, например, SQL. Для других языков элемент отображать не нужно.
Создал команду:

```
    envStatusBarItem = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 80);
    envStatusBarItem.command = aseChangeEnvironmentCommand;
    context.subscriptions.push(envStatusBarItem);
```

устанавливаю слушателя

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(updateEnvStatusBarItemFn));
```

Кроме этого, в `package.json` добавил в `activationEvents` условие `"onLanguage:sql"`.

Показываю и прячу элемент статус-бара следующим образом:

```
    const updateEnvStatusBarItemFn = () => {
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (editor) {
            if (editor.document.languageId === 'sql') {
                let aseCurrentServer = context.globalState.get('aseCurrentServer', '');
                envStatusBarItem.text = `ASE[${aseCurrentServer}]`;
                envStatusBarItem.show();
            }
            else {
                envStatusBarItem.hide();
            }
        }
        else {
            envStatusBarItem.hide();
        }
    };
```

Проблема заключается в том, что расширение активируется при смене языка в редакторе на SQL или открытии файла *.sql (в соответствии с условием в package.json). Элемент статус-бара показывается, но потом расширение считается активным и функция отображения/скрытия элемента статус-бара отрабатывает только на программно-установленном обработчике `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` при переключении вкладок. Я не смог найти слушателя, связанного со сменой языка, на которого можно было бы повесить свой обработчик. 
А существует ли такой способ, или надо писать feature-request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ дали разработчики VSCode:
Когда меняется язык документа, вызываются события `onDidCloseTextDocument` и `onDidOpenTextDocument`.

Описание в коде VSCode:
[Ответ](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83009#issuecomment-545325408)